# Creating a column based on two columns in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe as below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ORDER':["A", "A", "A", "B", "B","B"], 'New1': [2, 1, 3, 4, np.nan, np.nan], 'New2': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 5, np.nan]})
df

    ORDER   New1    New2
0   A       2.0     NaN
1   A       1.0     NaN
2   A       3.0     NaN
3   B       4.0     NaN
4   B       NaN     5.0
5   B       NaN     NaN
```

I want to create a column "New" by merging the columns New1 and New2 in a way that if one of the columns is NaN and another one has the value, keep the value. Foe example New for row1 will be 2.

My expected output

```
    ORDER   New 
0   A       2.0 
1   A       1.0 
2   A       3.0 
3   B       4.0 
4   B       5.0 
5   B       NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

```
df["New"]= df.loc[:,["New1","New2"]].sum(axis=1).replace(0.0,np.NaN)
```

Answer (score 1):

(*Note:* At the end of this answer is the one-line solution.)

The series' method `.combine_first()` does what you wanted:

```
resulting_column = df.New1.combine_first(df.New2)
resulting_column
```

> ```
> 0    2.0
> 1    1.0
> 2    3.0
> 3    4.0
> 4    5.0
> 5    NaN
> Name: New1, dtype: float64
> ```

Then rename this series (see the last row — its name is `New1`)  to `New` and join  it with `df[["ORDER"]]`

```
resulting_column.name = "New"
df_result = df[["ORDER"]].join(resulting_column)
df_result
```

> ```
>   ORDER  New
> 0     A  2.0
> 1     A  1.0
> 2     A  3.0
> 3     B  4.0
> 4     B  5.0
> 5     B  NaN
> ```

---

One-line solution:

```
df_result = df[["ORDER"]].join(df.New1.combine_first(df.New2).rename("New"))
```